# Instal Ubuntu on Lenovo Miix 320 10iCR - Black screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my tablet PC Lenovo Miix 320.
It works fine except on boot : when the pc boots, the screen remains black. If I want to open it, and use the computer, i need to snap the lid onto the keyboard and wait for about 30s and, if i get chance, the screen will enlight when unsnap. If i get less chance i have to snap again, wait a little more and it will works when unsnap and if i don't get chance, i need to reboot with magic keys to be able to use the computer (after snap - wait - unsnap).
I tried all the tips found on the net, no success :

- Modifying grub by adding :

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset i915.modeset=1 fbcon=rotate:1 modprobe.blacklist=axp288_fuel_gauge"

  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

  GRUB_GFXMODE=800x1280
- Modifying  initramfs (changing MODULES=most by MODULES=list and editing modules)
- creating an upstart file in /etc/upstart(but upstart is deprecated)

Does somebody has an idea to solve my problem and gain a computer that works as it must does ?

Thanks !

NB: the blogs i used to perform the install :

- [Installing Ubuntu Linux on Lenovo Miix 320 Hybrid Laptop](https://esc.sh/blog/linux-on-lenovo-miix-320/)
- [Installing Linux Lubuntu 18.04.01 on Lenovo MIIX 320](https://peprasetya.blogspot.com/2018/09/lubuntu-180401-on-my-lenovo-miix-320.html)
- [Installing Lubuntu 17.10 on the Lenovo Miix 320-ICR](https://telegra.ph/Installing-Lubuntu-1710-on-the-Lenovo-Miix-320-ICR-01-19)
- [Debian Buster on a Lenovo Miix 320](https://machek.systems/debian-buster-on-lenovo-miix-320/)

NB 2 : no camera or SD card but it's not my question, only to inform.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling while in tablet mode, without keyboard?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Windows 10 (upgraded from the originally installed Windows 8) on a Lenovo Flex10. I attribute it to a hardware or driver limitation and I have learned to live with it.